# Flutter - Drawer as sub-class not updating

Tags: class, dart, flutter, drawer

I'm a fairly inexperienced coder.

I have a Drawer which I have created as a separate class. The issue I'm having is the dynamic data for the Drawer is not populating.

I am expecting the data being retrieved from Shared Preferences should populate the third line of my view with the value of `currUserL`.

It's being evaluated correctly, and returns the value of `currUserL` to the console, but is not updated in the Drawer.

I've loaded up a about button (triggering the update method) that works when pressed manually, but data persists only while the drawer remains open. It reverts when the drawer is closed.

**drawerPatient.dart**

```
class DrawerPatient extends StatefulWidget {
  DrawerPatient({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DrawerPatientState createState() => new _DrawerPatientState();
}

class _DrawerPatientState extends State<DrawerPatient> {
  String currUserL = "nv3";

  Future getPref() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    currUserL = prefs.getString('currUserLast');

    debugPrint('user: $currUserL');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getPref();
  }

  void update() {
    setState(() {
      getPref();
    });
  }
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new DrawerHeader(
              child: new Text('Patient Management'),
              ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text('search'),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text(currUserL),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            new Divider(),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text('About'),
              onTap: update,
            ),
          ],
        ));
     }
 }
```

**userList.dart**

```
class UserList extends StatefulWidget {
  UserList({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final String titleHead = "User List";

  @override
  _UserListState createState() => new _UserListState();
  }

class _UserListState extends State<UserList> {
  : sortStr}, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    setState(() {
      data = json.decode(response.body);
    });
    }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.makeRequest();
//    DrawerPatient().createState().update();
  }


  void _refresh() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(

          title: new Text("Patient List"),

      drawer: new DrawerPatient(key: new UniqueKey()),
...
```

**Drawer when opened**

[image: Drawer when opened]

**Drawer after clicking about (update)**

[image: Drawer after clicking about (update)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer, thanks to @Dinesh for pointing me in the right direction.

The answer was to put the setState as a dependency on the async get prefs.

```
Future getPref() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

setState(() {
  currUserI = prefs.getString('currUserId');
  currUserF = prefs.getString('currUserFirst');
  currUserL = prefs.getString('currUserLast');

  debugPrint('user: $currUserL');
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
Future getCurrentUser() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  return prefs.getString('currUserLast');
}

void update() {
  val tempName = getCurrentUser();
  setState(() {
     currUserL = tempName;
  });
}
```

**Reason:** Basically **wait** for the `async` method before calling `setState`

Comment: Thanks, that didn't work, but it did get me in the right directon.

Comment: What happened? It should have worked. I saw your another answer. But that just a code movement.

Comment: Future returns a Future Object, to I couldn't assign it to String (currUserL. Even with Future<String> evoked. Parsing getCurrentUser() to string produced Future<String> object. update was only called manually, so did not set the state on load of the widget.

Comment: Got it. I didn't compile. Thanks for the response